# Post a List<Interface> .net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, custom-model-binder

I'm building a dynamic form creator in .net core. A "form" will consist of many different form elements. So the form model will look something like this:

```
public class FormModel {
  public string FormName {get;set;}
  public List<IElements> Elements{get;set;}
}
```

I have classes for `TextBoxElement`, `TextAreaElement`, `CheckBoxElement` that all implement the `IElemets` interface. And I have `EditorTemplates` for each element. The code to render the form works great. Though posting the form does not work because of the `List` of Interfaces.

I've been looking on how to implement a custom model binder, and seen some  few examples on the web but I did not get anyone to work.

I would appreciate if someone could show me how to implement a custom model binder for this example.

Plan B:
Post form as json to a web api and let JSON.Net covert it. I have tried it and it worked. In startup.cs i added:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto);
```

It returns type when it has to, eg. the objects in the Elements-list but not on the FormModel. But i really would like to know how to solve it with a custom model binder instead.

Comment: How would the model binder know which type to instantiate for the list elements when posting?

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down. I suppose you would have to post some additional information which would let your custom model binder know what type of Class to instantiate.

Comment: I think JSON.NET can handle types by serialising/deserialising the type name. If you're using JSON, then perhaps you can leverage that some how.

Comment: My thought was to have hidden fields with the type.
<input type="hidden" name="Elements[1].Type" value="MyNamespace.TextBoxElement" />

Comment: JSON.Net can deserialize if you include a $type parameter with the type if you do something lite this.

 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormModel>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });


Im not sure how you add this setting to it works when posting to a web api. Also in that case i would only want this setting when posting json, but not on return, any one now if that's possible ?

Comment: So, are you currently posting KeyValues pairs or JSON? And if it's KeyValue pairs, can you change it to JSON?

Comment: Currently I am posting KeyValue pairs. Regular form post, and i think best solution would be with a custom model binder, then it will work both if i post as json or as a regular form, right? But as plan b i've been considering to post form as json instead and configure JSON.Net to handle it, Im not sure how i do that either thou, but I haven't really looked into plan B yet. All ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this works for me. I'm still getting to grips with the new model binding so I may be doing something silly but it's a start!

## TEST FORM

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[0].Value" value="Hello" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[0].Type" value="InterfacePost.Model.Textbox" />

    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[1].Value" value="World" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[1].Type" value="InterfacePost.Model.Textbox" />

    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[2].Value" value="True" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Elements[2].Type" value="InterfacePost.Model.Checkbox" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

## INTERFACE

```
public interface IElement
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

## TEXTBOX IMPLEMENTATION

```
public class Textbox : IElement
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

## CHECKBOX IMPLEMENTATION

```
public class Checkbox : IElement
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

## MODEL BINDER PROVIDER

```
public class ModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(IElement))
        {
            return new ElementBinder();
        }

        // else...
        return null;
    }
}
```

## MODEL BINDER

```
public class ElementBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(IElement))
        {
            var type = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue($"{bindingContext.ModelName}.Type").FirstValue;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type))
            {

                var element = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type)) as IElement;

                element.Value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue($"{bindingContext.ModelName}.Value").FirstValue;

                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## HOOK UP MODEL BINDER PROVIDER

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ModelBinderProvider());
        });
    }
}
```

## FORM MODEL

```
public class FormModel
{
    public string FormName { get; set; } // Not using this

    public List<IElement> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

## ACTION

Notice the three types, Textbox, Textbox and Checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I tried this example.
bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue returns null
bindingContext.ModelName is an empty string

Comment: Never mind I missed the name="Elements[0].Type" in the html

Comment: This works well, however if the List<IElements> happens to have no items, then the whole Form model is returned as null. What could be done to solve that problem?

Comment: @Tak90 If it's null - I guess it's because no data has been POSTed. Could you simply just check for a null in code?

Comment: @LeeGunn Thanks getting back to me. The issue is that receiving an empty list in our case is still valid, so we would expect a model with a name but an empty or null list. However, upon looking at my code I have realised that it is not your code that misbehaving, but rather an error in mine. See my question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55759979/how-to-handle-model-binding-of-complex-type-with-list-of-interfaces-and-nested-l), I have answered it myself. Many thanks.