# How to handle model binding of Complex Type with List of interfaces and nested list of interfaces with possibly no values

Tags: c#, model-binding, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I have successfully(maybe not elegantly) created a model binder that will bind a List of Interfaces on post. Each interface has separate properties and some have a nested List of another interface. The list of interfaces get displayed correctly in the view and so do the nested list items. On post everything works, the custom model binders get called and the correct types get built. The issue that has me stuck is that if a nested List of interfaces has no items to display, on post back the model binder will not build that object up and any objects after that.

I am using razor pages and their respective page models. I make use of the 
`[BindProperty]` annotation inside the pagemodel.

### Interfaces and objects

Trimmed down Interfaces with concrete implementations: I have trimmed down the classes and omitted unnecessary code with ..

```cs
public interface IQuestion
{
    Guid Number{ get; set; }
    string Text{ get; set; }
    List<IAnswer> AnswerList{ get; set; }
    ..
}
```

```
public interface IAnswer
    {
        string Label { get; set; }
        string Tag { get; set; }
        ..
    }
```

```
public class MetaQuestion: IQuestion
    {
        public int Number{ get; set; }
        public string Text{ get; set; }
        public List<IAnswer> AnswerList{ get; set; }
        ..
    }
```

```
public class Answer: IAnswer
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        ..
    }
```

### Razor page model

```
public class TestListModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IDbSession _dbSession;

        [BindProperty]
        public List<IQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

        public TestListModel(IDbSession dbSession)
        {
            _dbSession= dbSession;
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            //just to demonstrate where the data is comming from
            var allQuestions = await _dbSession.GetAsync<Questions>();

            if (allQuestions == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load questions.");
            }
            else
            {                
                Questions = allQuestions;
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            //do something random with the data from the post back
            var question = Questions.FirstOrDefault();
            ..          
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

### Generated Html

This is the generated html of the code that does not work. One of the Question items specifically the second item in the list, does not have any `Answers` in the `AnswerList`.

As we can see, the second Question in the list has no 'Answer' items in the AnswerList'. This means that on post back, I only receive the first Question in the list. If I remove the second Question from the list then I get all the questions back.

I have removed all styling, classes and divs for the sake of brevity.

For **Question 1**:

```
<input id="Questions_0__Number" name="Questions[0].Number" type="text" value="sq1">
<input id="Questions_0__Text" name="Questions[0].Text" type="text" value="Are you:">
<input name="Questions[0].TargetTypeName" type="hidden" value="Core.Model.MetaData.MetaQuestion, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Tag field is required." id="Questions_0__AnswerList_0__Tag" name="Questions[0].AnswerList[0].Tag" type="text" value="1">
<input id="Questions_0__AnswerList_0__Label" name="Questions[0].AnswerList[0].Label" type="text" value="Male">
<input id="Questions_0__AnswerList_0__TargetTypeName" name="Questions[0].AnswerList[0].TargetTypeName" type="hidden" value="Core.Common.Implementations.Answer, Core.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
```

For **Question 2**:

```
<input id="Questions_1__Number" name="Questions[1].Number" type="text" value="sq1">
<input id="Questions_1__Text" name="Questions[1].Text" type="text" value="Are you:">
<input name="Questions[1].TargetTypeName" type="hidden" value="Core.Model.MetaData.MetaQuestion, Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
```

The rest of the questions after question 2 are similar to question 1.

### Custom Model Binders and providers

I understand that this isn't the best way to do this, and including the `TargetTypeName` is not ideal. There really isn't much out there that I could find that helps with this problem. I am newbie when it comes to ASP web dev.

```
public class IQuestionModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder> modelBuilderByType;

        private readonly IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider;

        public IQuestionModelBinder(IDictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder> modelBuilderByType, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
        {
            this.modelBuilderByType = modelBuilderByType ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilderByType));
            this.modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelMetadataProvider));
        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var str = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, "TargetTypeName");

            var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, "TargetTypeName"));

            if (modelTypeValue != null && modelTypeValue.FirstValue != null)
            {
                Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelTypeValue.FirstValue);
                if (this.modelBuilderByType.TryGetValue(modelType, out var modelBinder))
                {
                    ModelBindingContext innerModelBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
                        bindingContext.ActionContext,
                        bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                        this.modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelType),
                        null,
                        bindingContext.ModelName);

                    modelBinder.BindModelAsync(innerModelBindingContext);

                    bindingContext.Result = innerModelBindingContext.Result;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And the provider:

```
 public class IQuestionModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(IQuestion))
            {
                var assembly = typeof(IQuestion).Assembly;
                var metaquestionClasses = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                    .Where(t => !t.IsInterface || !t.IsAbstract)
                    .Where(t => t.BaseType.Equals(typeof(IQuestion)))
                    .ToList();

                var modelBuilderByType = new Dictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder>();

                foreach (var type in metaquestionClasses)
                {
                    var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
                    var metadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);

                    foreach (var property in metadata.Properties)
                    {
                        propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
                    }

                    modelBuilderByType.Add(type, new ComplexTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders: propertyBinders));
                }

                return new IMetaQuestionModelBinder(modelBuilderByType, context.MetadataProvider);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Similar for the IAnswer interface (could potentially refactor to not have 2 binders):

```
  public class IAnswerModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder> modelBuilderByType;

        private readonly IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider;

        public IAnswerModelBinder(IDictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder> modelBuilderByType, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
        {
            this.modelBuilderByType = modelBuilderByType ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilderByType));
            this.modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelMetadataProvider));
        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var str = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, "TargetTypeName");

            var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, "TargetTypeName"));

            if (modelTypeValue != null && modelTypeValue.FirstValue != null)
            {
                Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelTypeValue.FirstValue);
                if (this.modelBuilderByType.TryGetValue(modelType, out var modelBinder))
                {
                    ModelBindingContext innerModelBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
                        bindingContext.ActionContext,
                        bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                        this.modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelType),
                        null,
                        bindingContext.ModelName);

                    modelBinder.BindModelAsync(innerModelBindingContext);

                    bindingContext.Result = innerModelBindingContext.Result;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And the provider:

```
 public class IAnswerModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(IAnswer))
            {
                var exportedTypes = typeof(IAnswer).Assembly.GetExportedTypes();

                var metaquestionClasses = exportedTypes
                    .Where(y => y.BaseType != null && typeof(IAnswer).IsAssignableFrom(y) && !y.IsInterface)
                    .ToList();

                var modelBuilderByType = new Dictionary<Type, ComplexTypeModelBinder>();

                foreach (var type in metaquestionClasses)
                {
                    var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
                    var metadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);

                    foreach (var property in metadata.Properties)
                    {
                        propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
                    }

                    modelBuilderByType.Add(type, new ComplexTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders: propertyBinders));
                }

                return new IAnswerModelBinder(modelBuilderByType, context.MetadataProvider);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

These are both registered as follows:

```
  services.AddMvc(
                options =>
                {
                    // add custom binder to beginning of collection (serves IMetaquestion binding)
                    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new IMetaQuestionModelBinderProvider());
                    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new IAnswerModelBinderProvider());
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2));
```

I have tried to provide as much as info as possible.

I have been on this for days and eventually have got all the bindings to work except for this one case.

SO posts that helped get this far:

- [How to extend complextypemodelbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643025/how-to-extend-complextypemodelbinder)
- [Post a list interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062386/post-a-listinterface-net-core-1-0)

I understand that the model binders work with recursion, which leads me to believe that something is happening that is stopping execution as soon as it hits the `Question` with no `AnswerList` values.

The only thing I noticed is that the `AnswerList` `Tag` property in the html has the `data-val` set to true and `data-val-required` as well.

`<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Tag field is required." id="Questions_0__AnswerList_0__Tag" name="Questions[0].AnswerList[0].Tag" type="text" value="1"`

I am not sure why this would be the case. I have not explicitly set this. The class is in a different namespace and we would rather not apply data annotations all over the classes.

This could be what is breaking the binding as it is expecting a value, however I cannot be sure.

Is this problem normal behaviour? If so what could the solution be?

Comment: It's not really clear what your specific question is. Looks more like you are looking for a code review. If you can simplify your code an ask a more specific question you will more likely get an answer.

Comment: Holy cow! Thats an insane amount of code to do something. I'm not even going there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall proceed to answer my own question. This solves the problem.
This is what my editor template looked like for a `Question`

```
@model MetaQuestion
<div class="card card form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <strong>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number, new { @class = "form-control bg-light", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "border:0px;" })
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-black-50">
        <h6 class="card-title mb-2 text-muted">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
        </h6>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AnswerList.Count; i++)
        {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].PreCode, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].Label, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].TargetTypeName)
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <input name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".TargetTypeName")" type="hidden" value="@this.Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName" />
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Towards the end you can see there are 2 columns that include `HiddenFor` helpers. I am using these to identify what Type the interface is which allows the custom Model Binders mentioned in my question to pick the relevant type.

What was not obvious to me was that when a 'Question' had no 'Answers' it was ignoring all the values within and after the for loop. So the custom binder was never able to find the type of the `Question` as that data was completely lost.

I have since proceeded to re-order the `Html.HiddenFor` helpers which has solved the issue. My editor now looks as follows:

```
@model MetaQuestion
<div class="card card form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="card-header">
        <input name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + ".TargetTypeName")" type="hidden" value="@this.Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName" />
        <strong>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Number, new { @class = "form-control bg-light", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "border:0px;" })
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-black-50">
        <h6 class="card-title mb-2 text-muted">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
        </h6>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AnswerList.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].TargetTypeName)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].PreCode, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AnswerList[i].Label, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @style = "background-color:white; border:0px;" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Placing it upfront makes sure it always exists. This may not be the best way to handle this whole situation, but at least it has solved the problem.